# how to convert NSData to char array containing hexa values

Tags: iphone

i am receiving NSData by following method

```
     - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
```

server send data in follwing format

```
                 04 01 00
```

as hexa values. so now need to convert this data into char array so that i can access every pair separately
please help

Comment: are you sure you receive hexadecimal values? i would say you just receive bytes. Can you dump the didReadWith:**data**?

Comment: server is sending data in above format , i need to convert that

Comment: Yes. But is that a string or did you shown use some bytes?! give use a clear info.

Comment: char a[7] = {0x01,0x05,0x00,0x06,0xE0,0x90,0x01} ;
   NSData *configurationdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:a length:7];

   
   //dataSent = [sendLeft1On dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [clientSocket writeData:configurationdata withTimeout:-1.0 tag:1];

Comment: i am sending data in this format , server is receiving correctly now i when server send it should receive and need to convert in , I cant see the server but by its confuguration document i came to know that server will send 04 01 00 in response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go like this if you'd like to compare byte by byte:

```
    //NSData *test; // assume this is your NSData containing 0x04 0x01 0x00

    char *ptr = (void *)[test bytes]; // set a pointer to the beginning of your data bytes
    if(*ptr == 0x04) {
        NSLog(@"okay,.. got a 0x04");
    }
    ptr++; // go to the next byte
    if(*ptr == 0x01) {
        NSLog(@"okay,.. got a 0x01");
    }
```

hope that does work for you.

Comment: can you help me to convert this char *ptr to NSString so that I can show on some label or alert