# How To convert NSData to Char?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, char, nsdata

I have a NSdata (**License_Data <0d2b3931 39323433 37363637 36360c79 70617963 6173682d 50445301 0010322d 22772a17 24599e96 88be9991 b2410106>) like this**

When i Convert this to char after this 00 ,It is not taking any value

> 0010322d
>   Char*c=[Lincense_Data bytes];

Is thr any method other than this which take even Zero also ,Anyone Please Help???

Comment: can you explain why are converting it into the `char`?

Comment: @Kamarshad I am converting all the data type data to char(in java byte) so that i can form one big data and send to server. but if NSdata contains 00 i am getting above problem. is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
unsigned char *bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];
```

also see this answer..

[how to convert NSData to char array containing hexa values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214990/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-char-array-containing-hexa-values)

Comment: In that link 00 is at last so it'll consider that as null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

For Objective-C++, This is how I convert the `NSData` to `char *`

```
NSData *data = [...]; // This is your data
if (data) {
    const void *_Nullable rawData = [data bytes];
    char *src = (char *)rawData;
}
```

Comment: To use Objective-C++, convert file extension from `.m` to `.mm`